# How connect Socket client in Visual C++ 2012 with Socket server in Python

Tags: python, sockets, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

*Hello programmers*, I have one Socket server in my PC with python when

> Port = 2525
>
> host = ""

I want that my Client in Visual C++ application can send a message and the server answer anything.
`Exactly: I need send with my Socket Client (Visual C++ Application) "Hello server" and my Socket Server (Python) Answer "Hi".`

I don't need the Code of Python Socket Server, most important is the Visual C++ 2012 Socket client

-Thanks

Comment: Try looking in the MSDN documentation. The complete client code you need is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx you just need to change the server address/port to connect to

Comment: Thank you (user91516841) I go to try with this...